# Update the remote URL for multiple Git repositories

Tags: git, powershell

I am looking for a simple way to update all the 'remote' URL's for my local git repositories on a Windows 10 client.

We have updated the URL on our server to be a HTTPS, instead of HTTP and the URL has changed from:

```
http://bitbucket.myserver.com
```

to:

```
https://bitbucket.myserver.com:8443
```

I have a powershell script for updating (pull) the repositories, but not sure how to change this to the command to update the remote URL:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object { Write-Host("`r`ngit pull for: '$($_.FullName)'") | git -C "$($_.FullName)" pull }
```

I need to incorporate the following command to the above PowerShell script:

```
git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After retrieving the original URL with `git remote get-url`, you can use [URI builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) to change the `Scheme` and `Port`. Using UriBuilder also makes it safe to run multiple times (idempotent):

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host("`r`ngit remote set-url for: '$($_.FullName)'")
    $url = git -C "$($_.FullName)" remote get-url origin
    $url = new-object System.UriBuilder -ArgumentList $url
    $url.Port = 8443
    $url.Scheme = "https"
    git -C "$($_.FullName)" remote set-url origin $url
}
```